# Increase the number of comments in the "previously entered comments" list when committing using subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

When I commit something using the Subclipse plugin in Eclipse, the dialog allows me to pick a previously entered comment and use its contents again for the current commit comment.

It however seems like this list is restricted to the 10 most recent comments. This is somewhat limiting. I have checked the settings and can't find a way to increase this number.

Does anyone here know of a way to increase this number? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no preference or setting to increase the size of the list.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. I opened a ticket: http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1569